# Unknown provider: $$MapProvider

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, bower

> Unknown provider: $$MapProvider <- $$Map <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- $$animateQueue

I have Unknown `$$MapProvider` Error While Using `'angular-animate'`

My `bower.json` look Like this:

```
 { 
   "angular": "^1.6.2",
   "angular-animate": "1.6.2",
 }
```

Comment: Did you include all the javascript sources on the page?

Comment: check the 2 files (angular.js and angular-animate.js and chekc if they're the same version) .. if not reinstall them with bower and be carefully of the same version

Comment: @thinkwinwin :Yes I have included the javascript sources

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi : Yes both of the modules are of same version (1.6.2)

Comment: mmm but are you tryng to use google maps or similar? ...

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad Try using angular 1.6.1 and angular-animate 1.6.1 instead of 1.6.2, unless you need  a particular feature from 1.6.2

Comment: @Katana24 : Thanks, i used the previous version of angular and angular-animate(1.5.8). Error is gone. Thanks

Comment: @ShakeelAhmad No problem. I had the exact same problem this morning and actually followed federico scamuzzi's advice so thank him :)

Answer (score 33):

Credit to federico - As discussed in the comments this can be caused by having different versions of `angular` and `angular-animate`. Try to bring these two inline and it should go away.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Look for a file called package.json

Comment: This solved it for me!!  :)     Don't forget to do an `npm install` once you've edited the `package.json` file, so that it will update the `angular-animate` package too.

Answer (score 17):

recently I've faced the same problem i think it must be compatibility issue of `angular` with `angular-animate` (though I'm not sure what the actual problem)

**Solution**

step1: **bower update**

now you will find couple of options here asking for a number to answer

step2: **press 4** and voila!!

Note: in my case option 4 was

```
angular#1.6.2 which resolved to 1.6.2 and is required by angular-animate#1.6.2
```

please find attached screenshot for more clarification
[image]